# Why is this an invalid LINQ cast?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, generic-list, iorderedenumerable

I put raw data into a generic list. Then, I put data calculated from that raw data into another generic list, this one:

```
private List<ItemTotalsAcrossMonths> itemTotalsAcrossMonthsList;
```

The data (both raw and calculated) need to be displayed sorted, ordered by Total Purchases, so I want the data to be sorted that way. Since ordering a generic list returns another generic list, I first tried reassigning the sorted data into the original generic list:

```
itemTotalsAcrossMonthsList = (List<ItemTotalsAcrossMonths>)itemTotalsAcrossMonthsList.OrderByDescending(x => 
x.TotalPurchases13);
```

...but the road I'm on is apparently paved with good intentions, because this codeside bomb explodes in my face:

[image]

I tried putting the vals into a separate generic list of the same type:

```
private List<ItemTotalsAcrossMonths> itemTotalsAcrossMonthsList;
private List<ItemTotalsAcrossMonths> itemTotalsAcrossMonthsListSortedByTotalPurchasesDescending;
. . .
itemTotalsAcrossMonthsListSortedByTotalPurchasesDescending = (List<ItemTotalsAcrossMonths>)itemTotalsAcrossMonthsList.OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalPurchases13);
```

...but the results were eerily similar.

What do I need to do to sort the generic list?

Comment: You're missing `ToList()` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing ToList() call.

LINQ methods return `IEnumerable<T>`, not `List<T>`, so you can't assume the implementation of interface is castable to `List<T>`.

You can call `ToList()` on LINQ query to get a list with the results.

Answer (score 1):

`OrderByDescending` returns an OrderedEnumerable.  Your type is a `List`.  Simply call `ToList()` after your `OrderByDescending` to get back to your type.

Answer (score 1):

The `OrderByDescending` method is a LINQ method. In general, LINQ works on `IEnumerable`s, not `List`s. You need to create a list from the `IEnumerable` using `ToList()` method:

```
itemTotalsAcrossMonthsList.OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalPurchases13).ToList();
```

Comment: Is a List not an IEnumerable?

Comment: @PeterSchneider A `List` is an `IEnumerable`, but an `IEnumerable` returned from a LINQ extension method is NOT a `List`.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean -- Linq works on *and results in* IEnumerables. True, that makes sense.